# What happens, when you immediately draw Exodia as Player 2?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm not too familiar with Yu-Gi-Oh, but I was wondering, what happens, when Player 2 (the one going second) draws all [Exodia, the Forbidden One](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Exodia_the_Forbidden_One) pieces in his opening hand?

Does he win automatically, before Player 1 goes into his Standby Phase, or does it have to wait, until the Draw/Standby phase of Player 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does he win automatically, before Player 1 goes into his Standby Phase, or does it have to wait, until the Draw/Standby phase of Player 2?

Exodia's win *condition* (note the word, it's not an effect), triggers immediately and not only in your turn, so you would win during the start of the Draw Phase of player's 1 turn.

Do note that this is not so common to happen, but it could eventually.

From Exodia's [rulings](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Exodia_the_Forbidden_One), emphasis mine:

> At the start of the Duel, if the player going second starts off with all five pieces of "Exodia the Forbidden One" in his hand, **then he wins the Duel before the first player draws his card**. The same applies if the player going first starts off with all five pieces. If both players have all five pieces of "Exodia the Forbidden One" in their hands at the start of the Duel, then the Duel ends in a DRAW.[13]

Comment: And more generally, the [zero turn victory](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Zero_Turn_Kill).

Comment: Was going to ask if it would be a zero turn kill. Perfect :)

Comment: Going further than the question, what would happen if both players draw all pieces for their opening hands? Would it be a draw?

Comment: @JoeW yes, the ruling also says that :) it's further down on the text I quoted: *"If both players have all five pieces of "Exodia the Forbidden One" in their hands at the start of the Duel, then the Duel ends in a DRAW."*

Comment: Okay, I am blind!

Comment: @JoeW lol, don't worry, probably a mirage due to the bold parts obscuring the rest of the text... but yeah it's a Draw... if it were up to me I'd say it would make more sense for the turn player to win but... :)

Comment: @DarkCygnus Wouldn't the player win, who first actually drew all 5 pieces? Is it in the rules, that both players draw their starting hand simultaneously, or does player 1 draw, then player 2, then player 1 starts their turn?

Comment: @Minix I think you are taking it a bit too far perhaps, the rules already indicate that it's a draw. Anyways, your initial hand is part of the game setup done before the actual turn begins in the first draw phase, so it is actually simultaneous if you may say

Comment: @DarkCygnus Makes sense :)